# Applying multiple conditional formatting to the same column with help of macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a formula to conditionally format text in a column based on the value from another cell (not in same column):

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 1
```

More detailed description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188612/formula-to-conditional-formatting-text-that-contains-value-from-another-cell).

I ran into problem while trying to apply this formula with the help of a macro I've recorded with "Record a macro" in Excel 2010.

Here is the process I do:

1) First I select the entire column (by clicking on column letter on top).

2) Then I go to "Conditional Formatting > New rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format", enter my formula and choose a fill color for my formatting.

3) I then repeat the step 2 for 3 other conditional formattings with different formulas as well as different fill colors:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 2

=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 3

=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 4
```

So here is the problem: while recording the macro I get the desired formatting, i.e. all the cells in A column are color coded depending on how many values from cells B1, C1, D1 and E1 match it's contents.

However when I try to run previously recorded macro on unformated column it doesn't work as intended, only changing color of some cells and only in one color.

So the question is: How do I apply multiple conditional formatting to the same column with help of macro in Excel 2010?

Below is a full macro code for your references:

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 2"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 3"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 4"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your formula from `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 1` (used with array entry) to `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $B$1:$E$1 & "*")) = 1` (used without array entry) fixes the issue. Actually thouse formulas give you the same result. So, this code works:

```
With Columns("A:A").FormatConditions
    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 1"
    With .Item(.Count).Interior
        .Color = 49407
    End With

    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 2"
    With .Item(.Count).Interior
        .Color = 5296274
    End With

    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 3"
    With .Item(.Count).Interior
        .Color = 15773696
    End With

    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,""*"" & $B$1:$E$1 & ""*"")) = 4"
    With .Item(.Count).Interior
        .Color = 255
    End With
End With
```

Not sure why, but when using your code, I should explicitly goto FormatConditions on the sheet and press "Apply" button for each rule to make it work. The most lakely issue is that thouse formulas are array formuas.

Comment: Ahh, worked like a charm, I was already starting to pull my hair :) I love how you make the code shorter too, looks very neat now, thanks a bunch!